# Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Help me fix the problem.'**data.json**' is in the same directory as my python script but when I run the program I get the following error

> Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'

```
import json

data = json.load(open("data.json))

def translate(w):
    return data[w]

word = input("Enter word: ")

print(translate(word))
```

Comment: There is a missing " in your code snippet, it should be `open("data.json")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research. I noticed that the catch here is to explore python's os module. Tutorials are available online from the various site.OS module helps your program communicate with the underlying Operating system. Issues I had raised are handled explicitly by the OS module.

Answer (score 10):

**it depends on the folder where you are running the script, not the script folder.**

For get the real path to the directory where your script are, you can use it :

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

open(dir_path + '/' + 'data.json')
```

Comment: @iEldenI am a bit new to coding. Please help me contextualize your answer in my program. Edit the program for me the way it can work.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem you must move the **data.json** file out of the the **python script folder**,and then run the program.

Your code is perfectly fine.